# C# How to multiple RowFilter in DataView

Tags: c#, rowfilter

I'd like to know how can I filter data based on multiple user's input in different textbox or combobox. It works but only the latest input. How can I link them together?

```
    private void text_Sname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);                      
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format ("[Supplier Name] LIKE '%{0}%'", text_Sname.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;            
    }

    private void text_Pnumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[Part Number] LIKE '%{0}%'", text_Pnumber.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }

    private void text_Dwgnumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[Drawing Number] LIKE '%{0}%'", text_Dwgnumber.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

Any answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can save your filter in a variable like this:

```
string m_currentFilter=string.Empty;
string m_partNumberFilter=string.Empty;
string m_drawingNumberFilter=string.Empty;
```

then write a method like

```
 private void applyFilter()
{
    generateFilter(m_drawingNumberFilter);
    generateFilter(m_partNumberFilter);
}

private void generateFilter(string filter)
{
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
  {
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_currentFilter))
    {
      m_currentFilter=filter;
    }else
    {
       m_currentFilter+= " AND " + filter;
    }
   }
 }
```

Then you will use it like this:

```
    private void text_Pnumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            m_partNumberFilter=string.Format("[Part Number] LIKE '%{0}%'", text_Pnumber.Text);
            applyFilter();
            dv.RowFilter = m_currentFilter;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        }

private void text_Dwgnumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
       m_drawingNumberFilter= string.Format("[Drawing Number] LIKE '%{0}%'", text_Dwgnumber.Text);
        applyFilter();
        dv.RowFilter = m_currentFilter;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

This should only be an inspiration how you can do that, it's not porposed for using in production :-)

Comment: Thanks. Basically It works but when I delete the character from the text box it doesn't unfilter the dataview. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The apply filter method only add filter rulez. May you have to change the code that only one filter per field get applyed. (Regex, string.replace....)

Comment: I don't really understand, I am newbie in coding. Could you please write down? :)

Comment: Usualy this isn't a "write your Code Service", but I have the idea edited to give you a start point

Comment: I know and I really appreciate your help! Unfortunately, there is a Syntax Error in **dv.RowFilter = m_currentFilter;**
Syntax error: Missing operand before 'And' operator.

Comment: there was a missing ";", I have corrected it... I wrote this with my phone for you.... :)

Comment: I am searching the root cause. I guess it's something different. It has still the same issue. (In my opinion that single, double quote missing.)
 **m_currentFilter += " AND " + filter;**

Comment: I didn't find the error. :/ Do you have any idea Maestro? :)

Comment: the "generateFilter" Method had a brace too much, that I have corrected now.  But I think you talk about an exception you get from SQL Server? Then please post me the value of m_currentfilter

Comment: I am using a ms access. Snapshot from the error:
[Photo Link](http://i.imgur.com/zgLgnfj.jpg?1)

Comment: For example when I hit "4" on the keyboard in the partnumber text field it works but when I hit one more character like "40" it dies. --- **"4"** m_currentfilter value **"[Part Number] LIKE '%4%'"** --- **"40"** m_currentfilter value **"[Part Number] LIKE '%4%' AND AND [Part Number] LIKE '%40%'".** --- There is a duplication somehow but I cannot remove. I hope It helps. Thanks once again your support :)

Comment: If I start with the drawing number it looks different: --- **"4"** m_currentfilter value **"[Drawing Number] LIKE '%4%' AND "** --- and it dies in the first hit.

Comment: This is not a Code writing Service here :)
I have modified it again, I think it should work now.